# ngx-bootstrap BsDatepickerModule doesn't work

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I installed ngx-bootstrap v1.9.3 to my Angular 4 project. I tried to use a
`BsDatepickerModule` but it didn't work for me.

This error message stated:

> 404 GET /bs-datepicker-view.html

My project code:

```
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),...]
})

export class AppModule(){}
```

Comment: this is confirmed issue, for system.js users. I will drop a note when fix will lend in v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Go to this path **"\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\bundles\ngx-bootstrap.umd.js"**
2.Search for **"bs-datepicker-view.html"** in ngx-bootstrap.umd.js
3.Change the TemplateURL location path from './bs-datepicker-view.html' to **'./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/themes/bs/bs-datepicker-view.html'**.

Its works so good.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, but this is rather a workaround than a solution. Every time you install the ngx-bootstrap package you will need to do this step. Anyway, it can save my butt at least. Problem was also reported as an issue on valor-software's github project github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/2678

Answer (score 0):

Myself too facing this same error... but the HTML file is inside "\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\datepicker\themes\bs\bs-datepicker-view.html"

Comment: I guess it may be from system.config-js or wrong imported modules. It would be better to see a workable BsDatepickerModule  tutorial by Valor. Their demo is not sufficient: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/index-bs4.html#/datepicker#basic

Answer (score 0):

I had to update ngm-cli (used for UMD bundling), but now this issue should go away in ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.6